# Problems with Jquery Mobile Storing information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Basically I'm using phonegap to make a jquery-mobile application and while I think the framework is excellent I'm relatively new to it and I'm having re-occuring problems with the framework storing information. This becomes apparent in this example:

**Application slowing down/crashing due to framework memory filling:**
My application will read various pieces of information from JSON files and dynamically create pages within the file. It works exactly as desired but there is 10 different html files with this javascript function and when one navigates between these the application quickly slows down and eventually may crash. I've been looking into this problem for some time and believed it was a problem with the DOM and I looked at this [Page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html) but still can't solve the problem. Here's the javascript method just as reference

```
 $(document).on("pageinit", "#Page1", function(){ 
  var info="";
  var dpages="";
  var pageno=1;  
  var imp= "Json/example.json";
  $.getJSON(imp, function(data) {
     $.each(data.tcontent, function(i, item) {
        if(item.Name=='Example'){
           var search=item.Variations;
           $.each(search, function(j, subitem) {

            info += '<a href="#Paged'+ pageno + ' " data-role="button" data-mini="true" rel="external">'+ subitem.condition +'</a><br>';

            dpages += '<div data-role="page"  data-theme="a" id="Paged' + pageno + '" data-dom-cache="true"> <div data-role="header" data-theme="c"><a data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="flip" data-icon="back"> Back</a> <h2>'+ subitem.condition +'</h2> </div> <div data-role="content" data-theme="c" id="Paged '+ pageno +'_Content">  <p class="infotexttitle">Likely Organisms: </p> ' + subitem.organisms + ' <p class="infotexttitle"> Antimicrobial & Dosage </p> ' + subitem.antimicrobial + '  <p class="infotexttitle"> Alternative Antimicrobial: </p> ' + subitem.alternative + ' <div data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d"> <h3> Comments: </h3> <p class="guidelinetext"> ' + subitem.comments + ' </p></div> </div> <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c"> <h2>(c) Darragh O Connor </h2></div> </div></div>';



            pageno++;                        
        });
 }
 $("#texts").empty().append(info).collapsibleset().trigger('create');
 $.mobile.pageContainer.append(dpages);
 }); }); });
```

I think there may be a simple way to wipe the information stored each time you navigate between the files. If anyone could shed some light on the situation it would be much appreciated. 

Thanks!

Comment: Please only ask one question per posting. This is so that "correct" answers are unambiguously correct.

Comment: Pages that are externally loaded are removed once you navigate away from them, but their traces remain in navigation history.

Comment: @Blazemonger I just edited it there. Do you've any idea what I should do?